# why split function behave like this in java?

Tags: java

if I do

```
    String a = ""
    String b = a.split(" ")[0];
```

It is not giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

but when I do

```
    String a = " "
    String b = a.split(" ")[0];
```

It is giving me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

again when I do

```
    String a = " abc"
    String b = a.split(" ")[0];
```

It is not giving me Exception 
WHY SO?

Comment: A bit unexpected:

"This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array."

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @MariusSolbakkenMellum: you're exactly right, post your comment as an answer!

Comment: @Marius - why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: I know I'm being pedantic, but none of these snippets compile.

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of weird.

Thing is, in your first example, the empty String "" is a String, not null. So when you say: Split this "" with the token " ", the patterns doesn't match, and the array you get is the original String. Same as if you did

```
String a = "abc";
String b = a.split(" ")[0];
```

The pattern to split doesn't match, so you get one token, the original String.

You get an exception on the second case because the COMPLETE content of your String is exactly the delimiter you've passed to split, so you end up with an empty array.

Let me know if you want some further details, but this is pretty much it.

Answer (score 2):

After:

```
String a = " "
String[] arr = a.split(" ");
```

`arr` is an empty array. That's why it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to access its first (and non-existant) element. Now, after:

```
String a = " abc"
String[] arr = a.split(" ");
```

`arr` has one element: `"abc"`, which is why no exception is thrown when you try to access its first element.

Answer (score 2):

**Case #1**

```
String a = ""
String b = a.split(" ")[0];
```

From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the
>   resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

So `split()` gives you a single-element array, consisting of the input string (`""`). Therefore there's no exception.

**Case #2**

```
String a = " "
String b = a.split(" ")[0];
```

From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting
>   array.

You have two such trailing empty strings, and nothing else. Therefore you get back a zero-size array, resulting in the exception.

**Case #3**

```
String a = " abc"
String b = a.split(" ")[0];
```

It's not much of a corner case as it clearly has to return *at least* one element, hence no exception.

Answer (score 1):

> String a = "";
>
> String b = a.split(" ")[0];

When you do this, since there is no 'split' character present, therefore no split action is performed and an array is returned with first and only element as an empty string.

> String a = " ";
>
> String b = a.split(" ")[0];

while in this case it tries to split the string but get no values to be placed in either side, therefore no array is created. thus when you are trying to access its 0th element, it is giving ArrayOutOfBoundException.

> String a = " abc";
>
> String b = a.split(" ")[0];

In this case, splitting takes place and "abc" is placed at 0th place (I guess) and you are left with an array with a size greater that 0. **Problem Solved!!**..

Answer (score 0):

It's always a possibility that `String.split()` will return an empty array if there is a complete match on the provided `regex`